# Discord.py how can I get the Voice channel ID of a user AND save it to a .txt file?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a Discord bot that the user can **assign** certain voice channels to make the bot join the voice channel automatically when a user joins there.

However I need to make something like a database to save the list of voice channels that are **assigned** as automatical join channels, to prevent the list of assigned channels getting lost when the bot is down.

I've written a code to save it into a .txt file, and the code is:

```
@bot.command()
async def assign(ctx):
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        save = open('C:\Discordbots\channels_database.txt','w')
        save.write(channel)
```

However when I run it, I get an error like this:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError:
Command raised an exception: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not VoiceChannel
```

I have no idea how to convert the voice channel id to **str**, and having str() around **channel** doesn't work, either.

Is there any way that i can do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ctx.author.voice.channel.name` like this:

```py
channel = ctx.author.voice.channel.name
```

or `ctx.author.voice.channel.id` (it will be the same even when you change the name of the channel):

```py
channel = str(ctx.author.voice.channel.id)
```

also good practice is to use `with` so I recommend to change your code to this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def assign(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel.name
    with open("C:\Discordbots\channels_database.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(channel)
```

Comment: I didn't know I could use .id for the ID of the channel.. Anyways, thank you so much!